# Test unknown data in Kmeans Clustering in R

Tags: r

For example, I have a dataset of X= {1, 1.5, 5, 3, 4, 3} and Y = {1, 1.5, 5, 4, 4, 3.5}. What i did is --

```
data <− read . csv (”exp . csv”) 
print ( data )
results <− kmeans(data , 2)
results
results $ size 
results $ cluster
plot (temp [ c(”X” , ”Y”) ] , col=results $ cluster )
```

Now I wanna check suppose (1,1) is in which cluster ? How can i do that?

Comment: `results$cluster` have labels that indicate the cluster membership, in your case `1,1,2,2,2,2` i.e. first two observations belong to cluster 1 and rest in cluster 2

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is an interesting question but it may be better suited for Cross Validated. Programmatically, the answer is no (I think). But the stats underpinning of validating kmeans algorithms may have more answers there.

Answer (score 0):

case 1: when you know that the point is in the dataset you clustered, e.g., (1,1)

```
point1 <- c(1,1)
results$cluster[which(data$X==point1[1] & data$Y==point1[2])]
#[1] 1
```

case 2 (general): when the point may / may not be there in the dataset you clustered

```
point2 <- c(3,4)
dimnames(results$centers) <- NULL
which.min(apply(results$centers, 1, function(x) sum((x - point2)^2)))
#[1] 2
```

It also works for a point in the dataset:

```
which.min(apply(results$centers, 1, function(x) sum((x - point1)^2)))
#[1] 1
```